# How do users avoid paying gas fees?

Tags: blockchain, gas, meta-transactions

I have this web app implemented in React typescript where users can create posts and in return for fulfilling these posts, they gain credits from the other users. These credits are stored on the blockchain and ideally, I wouldn't want the users to pay for gas fees when transferring the credits from one another.

I've read online for ways to avoid it and am uncertain about meta transactions.

This seems like the best way since each user would have a pub and priv key anyway for their wallet and an admin user with all the credits would hand out a base amount to each user on sign up. Therefore if the end user signs with their pub key and then the admin user pays for them, this seems like the best way.

Is there another way to avoid it or is this the best way? Sorry if I misued any of the terminology, I'm very much new to all of this.